Github Action and Wireguard
I'm trying to use wireguard in a Github Action to open a tunnel to my wg server.
I've tryied some actions like this, but all remains stuck on sudo wg-quick up ./wg0.conf, so I'm forced to terminate them.
This is the conf file I'm using:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = *****
Address = 10.2.53.3/32, fc10:253::3/128
DNS = 10.2.53.1, fc10:253::1

[Peer]
PublicKey = ******
PresharedKey = ******
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1, ::/1, 8000::/1
Endpoint = ******:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

There is an issue with the action itself or is the range of AllowedIPs too big?
Thank you

Please add your workflow in your question. Do you see anything in the logs? Are you able to use the same configuration to create a tunnel from your local machine? Please update your question with this info as well.
